# Запуск программы через sh файл

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется программа, которая при запуске требует определенных библиотек, путь к которым устанавливается через `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Можно, конечно, вписать эту переменную в `etc/profile`, но я хотел бы, чтобы программа запускалась через `bash` скрипт, аля:

```
#!/bin/bash
appname="proga"

DIR="dir_with_libraries"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR

appname "$@"
```

Но тут две проблемы:

1) если я установливаю этот скрипт в директорию `/usr/local/bin` то не могу запустить его без `sudo`

2) при ноборе из командной строки нельзя автодополнить название, а в конце еще и разрешение "sh" указывать надо.

Comment: `+x` добавили - сделали его исполняемым?

Comment: 1. `$ sudo chmod +x файл`. 2. так уберите суффикс `.sh`

Comment: после того как сделаете его исполняемым, просто из папки, полную команду Александр написал

Comment: я его уже сделал исполняемым, но все равно нужны права суперпользователя для его запуска

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, сделал исполняемым для всех или только для владельца (root'а)? на чтение тоже не забудь права дать всем... `ls -l` в студию ради конкретики...

Comment: все, теперь понял, спасибо всем

Comment: Кстати, расширения в unix не имеют никакого сокрального смысла. Они чисто для пользователя. Так что не хотите дописывать .sh не пишите его в названии файла :)

Comment: @Mike, тем не менее в некоторых трудных случаях, *file*, если я правильно помню, берёт в рассмотрение расширение, иначе как отличить, например, разные виды файлов, у которых mime type — plain/text? (И правильно писать сАкральный)

Comment: @0andriy А вот для этого в первой строке файла написана строка `#!/bin/bash`. При попытке запуска любого файла на выполнение сначала проверяется, не бинарный ли это исполнимый код (обычно ELF, a.out, ...), если нет - то интерпретация отдается командной оболочке, которая смотрит этот заголовок. Если заголовка не окажется или он не указывает на интерпретатор нужного типа, то командная оболочка сама попытается его интерпретировать, на этом все.

Comment: @Mike, ну не совсем так (просто). Определение формата запускаемого файла выполняется ядром, если мы говорим о Linux. Я же вам немного о другом, а именно о расширении. Или вы способны отличить без интерпретации содержимого, например, _*.bat_ файл от текстового файла в UNIX?

Comment: @0andriy Да, я считал что шебанг опознает оболочка. Но да, его интерпретирует действительно сам загрузчик в ядре. И тогда я действительно не понимаю, что вы хотите до меня донести. По крайней той фразой про 'file'. Главное - что файл правильного внутреннего формата будет запущен вне зависимости от расширения, а только основываясь на содержимом. О чем я собственно сразу и сказал, что расширение нужно только самому пользователю что бы понимать что это такое. Но при этом оно не обязательно

Comment: @Mike `man file`, не было возможности использовать обратную кавычку с телефона. Надеюсь так понятнее. И в довесок, файлы без шебанга тоже можно запускать явно. Как их отличить от текста, если не использовать расширение? Пытаюсь донести вам, что расширение в UNIX имеет значение, но не очень весомое — это правда.

Comment: @0andriy Не понимаю какое отношение имеет утилита file к загрузчику в ядре. Посмотрел все файлы `fs/binfmt_*.c` в ядре. Да нашелся очень интересный binfmt_misc, он (и только он) может понимать расширения файлов (или по сигнатуре внутри файла). Через его интерфейс `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` можно загрузить собственные описания интерпретаторов. Это для меня стало новостью. Спасибо за наводку. Правда на всех доступных мне системах там ничего не загружено, т.е. видимо это не является общераспространенной практикой (правда декстопных систем у меня под руками нет, только сервера).

Comment: @Mike не понимаю, почему на  возражения против вашего утверждения о ненужности расширений файлов вы уклонились в сторону загрузки (я подумал, что в этом есть какой-то сакральный смысл, пытался откорректировать ваши высказывания в процессе), но сейчас понимаю, что вы вообще не о том пошли рассуждать. Ещё раз (и он же последний): *Пытаюсь донести вам, что расширение в UNIX имеет значение, но не очень весомое...*